# I have an EJS Syntax Definition For Sublime Text - How Do I import it into Sublime 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, ejs

I have a Syntax definition for Sublime Text 3 I'd like to import for Win 10.  But I'm not sure how to import the files I've located on GitHub for .EJS files Syntax.

Is anyone experienced with doing this?  Thanks!

Here's the link for GitHub...
https://github.com/samholmes/EJS.tmLanguage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That GitHub repo is also on Package Control - https://packagecontrol.io/packages/EJS

Therefore, if you have Package Control installed, the simplest way to import the syntax definition is to just go to the Tools menu in ST -> Command Palette -> Package Control: Install Package, and select EJS from the list.

---

Alternatively, you can download the whole GitHub repository as a zip file from GitHub's website, then go to the Preferences -> Browse Packages menu in ST, then create a folder called `EJS`, and extract the zip file there.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm.  I didn't realize it was so simple as I've never installed any syntax definitions for ST3 so far.  But thanks for the information.  Problem solved.

Comment: Most packages include some installation instructions in their readme, and without that - unless you've seen instructions for other packages - it's not obvious at all, so don't feel bad about not knowing :)